# cannot calibrate touchscreen

Tags: 11.04, touchscreen

I installed 11.04 on a WeTab (although wetab os is now gonne, only 11.04 now). I use the eGalax Inc. USB TouchController device driver. I want to calibrate the screen using Touchscreen Settings, but I get the following errir message:

"Unable to start calibration. Exclusive access to the pointer could not be obtained"

This is annoying because the calibration is slightly wrong, meaning I can't reach the right of the screen including shut down/log out etc.

Is there a fix for this, or a way to manually change the calibration settings?

Comment: i've given up in 11.04 for now. it isn't ready for my device, much better on a netbook without touchscreen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hey dude iv been having a similar issue....

to fix this i installed xinput-calibrator

```
 sudo apt-get install xinput-calibrator
```

you can then run it from System > Administration > Calibrate Touch-screen

after you have calibrated it will show a terminal output that looks similar to this

```
   Warning: multiple calibratable devices found, calibrating last one (eGalax INC. USB TouchController)
    use --device to select another one.
Calibrating EVDEV driver for "eGalax INC. USB TouchController" id=12
    current calibration values (from XInput): min_x=0, max_x=4095 and min_y=0, max_y=4095

Doing dynamic recalibration:
    Setting new calibration data: 77, 3935, 115, 3984


--> Making the calibration permanent <--
  copy the snippet below into '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf'
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "calibration"
    MatchProduct    "eGalax INC. USB TouchController"
    Option  "Calibration"   "77 3935 115 3984"
EndSection
```

ignore most of this the only bit you need is

```
Option  "Calibration"   "77 3935 115 3984"
```

in terminal type

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf
```

and add the Calibration option to your touch-screen section

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
        Option "Calibration" "77 3935 115 3984"
EndSection
```

for the /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf  simple instruction can be found on  http://gnometechblog.weebly.com/1/post/2012/03/first-post.html

Comment: hey, thanks for posting the answer. i don't have 11.04 installed at the moment but will try your method if I put it back in the future.